# PHP API getting empty JSON request in POST

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am trying to develop small API code in php, which will send POST request in json format using PHP curl (from client side). And at receiving side(at server side)  I want to parse the request and process it. but at receiving side it gives me empty array in post field.
Below is my code

**Client side:**

```
<?php

    $data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xdata=".$data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   
    echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

**At server side:**

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST);

?>
```

> Blockquote
>   Array ( )
>   Blockquote

It always gives me empty POST array at server side.
Am I doing things wrong or is there another way to parse the request?
Please guide me.

Comment: So, PHP is always on the server. PHP never runs on the client.

Comment: Try adding - curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Answer (score 9):

You can use **php://input** read-only stream to access JSON post data instead of **$_POST** like this

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

It will give you POST data as is. You will be able to decode it using json_decode() later.

**Example code -**

```
<?php 
   $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Vikesh, It is working now. but it is not possible to get the data from POST?

Comment: @Shirish, `$_POST` is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request. For the reference see this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: If my answer is helpful then accept this.

Comment: " application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is worked in my case. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong content length with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` header. Your overall post string is `strlen("xdata=".$data_string)` whereas you are using `strlen($data_string)`.

Also, you are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for posting, but mentioning the content type forcefully as `application/json`

So remove the following block from your code and you should be fine.

```
// Remove it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
```